# How to set Position of jQuery UI draggable relative to parent and position propert to absolute

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to set position of my jQuery UI Dragable element to absolute so it takes no space in the document flow. But after doing this when I try to drag it. It moves out of the document. Is there a way so I can set its position relative to position of its container div. Thanks

Comment: Show relevant code please.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the way it's documented on http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement

For example:

```
$('.divelement').draggable({
  containment: $('body')
});
```

Or explain it a with jsFiddle, please.

Comment: Because the default value of property position is relative so it takes some space. I want that to be absolute, so it would not take space..